# Turn-based game (game board type) online

Tags: javascript, html

I`ve been coding a game in javascript, actually, a gameboard turn-based game. I started doing the solo player, then, a auto-turn duo-game, each click changes the turn (automatically each clicks paints different color and each player has a score board) the problem appears when I wan to scale it to a online game, each player is in a different client. I learned node.js/socket.io so I know how to code up a server/client, but where is the actual problem? how I set the turns? how I set up basic identifiers or whatever I need to change turns. I thought server has a var with the current player to play (for example Blue), but how to set each client`s color? Im a little confused!

Thanks!!!

Standard structure:
     -Connect server. Client
     -New game. Client
     -Search for a opponent Client
     -Opponent found. Client
     -Server creates a game, gameboard and sets the "turn-based" logic, how?
     -Client 1 plays his turn.
     -Server changes the turn to client 2, how???
     -Client 2 plays his turn
     -Server changes the turn to client 1, how???

Im confused about the "how?", in general, how is a turn-based online logic done???

Comment: Can you be more specific? And maybe post the code you're having trouble with?

Comment: "Where is the actual problem?" - good question.

Comment: #1 edited to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would use a database to store my data. In the database you can identify the players and their actions, using ids. You can then load the data with your server and display it in your pages. Also, you can handle their actions as well. Read tutorials, learn more about databases and I believe your problems will be solved.

Comment: What DB you suggest me? The famous MongoDB? SQL?

Comment: This is a subjective question. If a database is good for one it might be bad for the other one. This forum focuses on facts. In fact I shouldn't tell you which database is good for you. Study them for a while and when you know which database is good for you then you know you are ready to go forward.

Comment: @user2657856, i wouldnt use a database (takes a lot of time to master). plain text is enough to store such information.

Comment: @Rookie when you are developing an application you always have to assume that it will become successful with a lot of users doing a lot of stuff. If it will become successful, then your efforts are justified, if not, then still your work was elegant and you have learned from it. If you are not assuming that and it still becomes successful, then you will have trouble with scalability.

Comment: @LajosArpad, i think such attitude isnt healthy. nevertheless, a TXT file per game isnt going to make any problems with even trillion users, it will still be just trillion TXT files. no problems. You cant, and should not try to predict everything in life. if you start by "this should work in the year 5000 too, and must be absolutely perfect!" attitude, you get no work done. the question writer is obviously a total newbie; too much complexity will just overwhelm him. its better to master one thing at once, not try to eat the whole cake at once.

Comment: @Rookie, let's suppose you are not using a database. Then you do not have concurrent access support. What if the scheme of your data is changed? You change all your text files? What if you change them in the wrong way? What if you want to speed up your application through data access optimization? Also, your backup feature will not be simplified at all this way. Databases were invented with the basic idea that it is far not optimal to use file systems. Also, he is a newbie but he should want to become a professional. So he should learn a lot.

Comment: Basically you are telling him that he shouldn't learn useful things for now, because there is an alternative of using a deprecated and bad strategy. This is anti-progress and has several serious drawbacks. Instead of solving all the problems which will arise from using files instead of a database he should learn how to use a DBMS. How do you protect privacy with online accessible files?

Comment: @LajosArpad, changing the structure of data, is as slow in both systems. you cant read the harddisk from different places at same time even if you used a database. i also doubt there is any possibility for speeding up, or need for that, for application which file read/write time is 50ms at most. some people code for hobby, and doesnt think about the fame and glamour they could get with their tic-tac-toe game every night they go to bed. "if you dont need it, dont use it." - my five cents. premature optimization is bad, you should know that.

Comment: Changing the structure of data means that you run a few alters and rebuild your entity sets if you work elegantly. If you use files, you need to write a few functions and run them on all your stored files and you pray that there are no bugs in your code. If you have billions of files stored on your server, then it will be slow. Premature optimization is for instance creating indexes when you do not need them yet. Using files instead of databases is not the lack of premature optimization. It is bad practice.